# drupal : how to restrict users to only be able to see one contentType

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have created a contentType called "Price".

I wish to set permissions so that users of the role "PriceUsers" can only see content of contentType "Price"

I am using drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

Untick all "access" rights on all other roles for all other content types in Permissions section.